# Force SSL on htaccess for WordPress date redirects

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a long-time blog that was using the day and name format:

```
https://www.example.com/2018/05/30/sample-post/
```

After the first year, I decided that I would be better off without the date in the URL.  I changed my permalinks in WordPress and then added the following to my htaccess file to redirect the old posts:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ http://www.fakedomain.com/$4`

This worked well until a couple years later when I migrated over to SSL.  I then just adjusted the above rule to be:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ https://www.fakedomain.com/$4`

Everything is working just fine.  However, "Why No Padlock?' flags it with:

> Your webserver is not forcing the use of SSL.
>   You may want to add a redirect to ensure a secure connection is used.

It then recommends that I add this to the htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} fakedomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.fakedomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

However, if I add that, the site breaks.  I don't understand the rules enough, what's the best way to use the SSL redirect in combination with old redirect?

As a side note, I have other domains on this as well, so there are already some other rules in there.  I don't think this should affect the above, but figured I'd mention it in case it's relevant:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^anotherdomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.anotherdomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.andanotherdomain\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using redirection HTTP to HTTPS like this, then your redirection rule, and finally standard wordpress htaccess config.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# HTTP to HTTPS redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Your redirect rule
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ http://www.fakedomain.com/$4

# Standard WordPress config
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, Bartosz - I'm not real good at reading what this actually does.  Does this handle the redirection of the posts with the old date format to the new as well (eliminating the date, month, and year)?  Or is this something separate I should use before or after that RedirectMatch section?

Comment: i have updated the code above, let me know if it works :)

Comment: Didn't work.  All the other sites work Ok with that in there, but the main site gives me:

The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.  This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

I'm going to mess with it a little more and see if I can figure out what's going on.